# Not able to create deployment or anything in the provided EKS luster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I am new to `Kubernetes` and using EKS cluster end-point provided by third party. I trying to create a simple ngnix deployment using following command:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx-depl --image=nginx
```

It gives me following error:

```
error: failed to create deployment: admission webhook "validate.kyverno.svc" denied the request:

resource Deployment/comp-dev/nginx-depl was blocked due to the following policies

edison-platform-policy-disallow-pod-without-resources:
  validate-resources: 'validation error: Error : Unable to install - container spec does not specify resource request. Rule validate-resources[0] failed at path /spec/template/spec/containers/0/resources/requests/. Rule validate-resources[1] failed at path /metadata/labels/AllowContainerWithoutResourcesRequests/.'
edison-platform-policy-disallow-privileged-container:
  autogen-validate-allowPrivilegeEscalation: 'validation error: Privileged mode is not allowed. Set allowPrivilegeEscalation to false. Rule autogen-validate-allowPrivilegeEscalation[0] failed at path /spec/template/spec/containers/0/securityContext/. Rule autogen-validate-allowPrivilegeEscalation[1] failed at path /spec/template/metadata/labels/AllowPrivilegedEscalation/.'
edison-platform-policy-disallow-root-user:
  autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot: 'validation error: Running as root user is not allowed. Set runAsNonRoot to true. Rule autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot[0] failed at path /spec/template/spec/securityContext/runAsNonRoot/. Rule autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot[1] failed at path /spec/template/spec/securityContext/runAsUser/. Rule autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot[2] failed at path /spec/template/spec/containers/0/securityContext/. Rule autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot[3] failed at path /spec/template/spec/containers/0/securityContext/. Rule autogen-validate-runAsNonRoot[4] failed at path /spec/template/metadata/labels/AllowRootUserAccess/.'
edison-platform-policy-disallow-unknown-registries:
  autogen-validate-registries: 'validation error: Unknown image registry. Rule autogen-validate-registries failed at path /spec/template/spec/containers/0/image/'
```

Is public image registry is blocked in ECS? Or do the third party EKS provider has not enabled the public docker repository?

Comment: the cluster seems to have a set of additional restrictions on kubernetes resources implemented. according to the error messages it is quite clear that you are missing resource requests and limits. the addional option: allowPrivilegeEscalation=false, runAsNonRoot=true.
and you either need to specify the complete registry (docker.io/nginx) or use one that is known to your cluster. ask cluster admins for supported registries in this case. however, you will not be able to create resurces with kubectl create due to the restrictions. rather supply complete yaml definitions

Comment: @meaningqo Thanks for you comment.  I have added resource and tried running it again. Now resource part of the error is gone. But there is still another issue regarding privilege mode. I am editing my question and putting that part too.

Comment: @meaningqo allowPrivilegeEscalation=false, runAsNonRoot=true worked. I didn't know that where to add it. I was supposed to add it in my yaml file only.

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cluster is installed with [Kyverno](https://thenewstack.io/kyverno-a-new-cncf-sandbox-project-offers-kubernetes-native-policy-management/). Your `create` request was rejected by this policy engine base on a policy setup by the provider. Try the following spec:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
      - name: busybox
        image: docker.io/busybox:latest
        command: ["sh","-c"]
        args: ["sleep 3600"]
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          runAsNonRoot: true
```

Note how to run Nginx as non-root is not cover here.